# How do you create an alias for iPhoto package folders in mountain lion?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, macos, photos.app, adobe-lightroom

Has the ability to create aliases to folders inside the iPhoto package file been disabled or removed?

I used to sync up my LightRoom library with iPhoto by using an alias to the Originals/Masters folder inside the iPhoto library package. But it now appears as disabled in the finder file menu and completely gone in the context menu and cannot figure out a way to create aliases to these type of folders.

Am I going to have to ditch iPhoto completely or is there a workaround for this?

**Edit:** [Example of what I mean](http://lightroomsecrets.com/2009/03/moving-your-images-from-iphoto-to-lightroom/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still is possible via a work around.

The right-click contextual menu does not contain an option *Make Alias* for the Originals/Masters directories, but it does for subdirectories. The option *Make Alias* always shows in the menubar under *File → Make Alias* but is greyed out for the Originals/Masters directories.

### Workaround

1. Go to a subdirectory of Originals/Master in Finder.
2. Create your alias, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
3. Open the *Info* of the created alias folder, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.
4. Click the button *Select new Original*
5. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to enter a custom path.
6. Enter your path, e.g. `/Users/my_name/Pictures/Aperture Library.aplibrary/Masters`
7. Rename the Alias folder.

[image]  [image]

Comment: awesome worked like a charm except its shift command g think you had a typo there

Comment: Oh yeah, will fix that...

Comment: and it wouldn't let me do it in a subfolder i had to go up to a parent folder not sure if this has anything to do with the fact i have this on a secondary drive or not but subfolders gave me the same disabled menu option

Comment: @ChrisMcGrath That's strange. I can create an alias for any folder in any subdirectory of `Masters`. I don't know about `Originals` as I don't have such a folder. But Aperture and iPhoto can now share the same Library. So it should work for both.